# Django serializer is not returning JSON data

Tags: json, django

I have a model Domain:

```
class Domain(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And a corresponding serializer:

```
class DomainSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Domain
        fields = ('name',)
```

I'm trying to serialize a queryset in a view like this:

```
def getDomains(request):
    domains =    Domain.objects.filter(name__startswith=request.GET['name_startsWith'])

    data = DomainSerializer(domains, many=True)
    print(data.data)
    return HttpResponse(data.data)
```

This is not working correctly, and data.data is :

```
[OrderedDict([('name', 'Math')])]
```

I would like to have a JSON object, something like:

{'name': 'Math'}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using **JsonResponse** to return the data:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
.....
return JsonResponse(data.data)
```

Comment: Thanks ! I also added safe=False to JsonResponse